# String matching two dataframes with a sliding window

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sliding-window

I have two df.

```
df1
       col1
    1    a
    2    b
    3    c
    4    c
df2
   setID col1
1      1    a
2      1    b
3      1    b
4      1    a
5      2    w
6      2    v
7      2    c
8      2    b
9      3    a
10     3    a
11     3    b
12     3    a
13     4    a
14     4    b
15     4    c
16     4    a
```

I'm using the following code to match them.

```
scorematch <- function () 
{
      require("dplyr")
      #to make sure every element is preceded by the one before that element
      combm <- rev(sapply(rev(seq_along(df1$col1)), function(i) paste0(df1$col1[i-1], df1$col1[i])));
      tempdf <- df2
      #group the history by their ID
      tempdf <- group_by(tempdf, setID)
      #collapse strings in history
      tempdf <- summarise(tempdf, ss = paste(col1, collapse = ""))
      tempdf <- rowwise(tempdf)
      #add score based on how it matches compared to path
      tempdf <- mutate(tempdf, score = sum(sapply(combm, function(x) sum(grepl(x, ss)))))
      tempdf <- ungroup(tempdf)
      #filter so that only IDs with scores more than 0 are available
      tempdf <- filter(tempdf, score != 0)
      tempdf <- pull(tempdf, setID)
      #filter original history to reflect new history
      tempdf2 <- filter(df2, setID %in% tempdf)
      tempdf2
    }
```

This code works great. But I want to take this further. I want to apply a sliding window function to get the df1 values I want to match against df2. So far I'm using this function as my sliding window.

```
slidingwindow <- function(data, window, step)
{
  #data is dataframe with colname
  total <- length(data)
  #spots are start of each window
  spots <- seq(from=1, to=(total-step), by=step)
  result <- vector(length = length(spots))
  for(i in 1:length(spots)){
    ...
  }
  return(result)
}
```

The scorematch function will be nested inside slidingwindow function. I'm unsure how to proceed from there though. Ideally df1 will be split into windows. Starting from the first window it will be matched against df2 using the scorematch function to get a filtered out df2. Then I want the second window of df1 to match against the newly filtered df2 and so on. The loop should end when df2 has been filtered down so that it contains only 1 distinct setID value. The final output can either be the whole filtered df2 or just the remaining setID. 
Ideal output would be either

```
  setID col1
1     4    a
2     4    b
3     4    c
4     4    a
```

or

```
[1] "4"
```

Comment: Can you explain, why the last a is also matched? I would not expect it to be matched as the next letter in the sequence in df1 is c. Is then the order of match not important? Also if I run only the score match function, I also get the matching for 1 with a b b a, where I'd would expect the second part. Can you elaborate further on the purpose of the matching? I think there might be a shorter approach with pasting and regex....

Comment: `tempdf <- pull(tempdf, setID) ::: Error in eval_tidy(enquo(var), var_env) : object 'setID' not found`

Comment: @kath The matching function is based on scores. I've set it so any score that isnt 0 will be returned. And it isnt looking for the perfect match. Just the closest match. The purpose is that I want to find out which one of my sets in df2 is the closest match to df1. And before you give me a simpler explanation of matching the whole df1 against df2, that is not what i require. I require df1 to be matched window by window to df2. And yes the order is important.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without using a `for`-loop. I use `stringr` because of its nice consistent syntax, `purrr` for `map` (although `lapply` would be sufficient in this case) and `dplyr` to `group_by` setID and collapse the strings for each group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
```

First I collapse the string for each group. This makes it easier to use pattern-matching with `str_detect`-later:

```
df2_collapse <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(setID) %>% 
  summarise(string = str_c(col1, collapse = ""))

df2_collapse
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#   setID string
#   <int> <chr> 
# 1     1 abba  
# 2     2 wvcb  
# 3     3 aaba  
# 4     4 abca
```

The "look-up" string is collapse as well and then the substrings (i.e. slding windows) are extract with `str_sub`. Here I work along the length of the string `str_length` and extract all possible groups following each letter in the string.

```
string <- str_c(df1$col1, collapse = "")

string
# [1] "abcc"

substrings <- 
  unlist(map(1:str_length(string), ~ str_sub(string, start = .x, end = .x:str_length(string))))
```

Store the substrings in a tibble with their length as score.

```
substrings
# [1] "a"    "ab"   "abc"  "abcc" "b"    "bc"   "bcc"  "c"    "cc"   "c" 

substrings <- tibble(substring = substrings, 
                     score = str_length(substrings))

substrings
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#    substring score
#    <chr>     <int>
#  1 a             1
#  2 ab            2
#  3 abc           3
#  4 abcc          4
#  5 b             1
#  6 bc            2
#  7 bcc           3
#  8 c             1
#  9 cc            2
# 10 c             1
```

For each setID with extract the maximum score it matches in the substring-data and the filter out the row with the maximum score of all setIDs.

```
df2_collapse %>%
  mutate(score = map_dbl(string, 
                          ~ max(substrings$score[str_detect(.x, substrings$substring)]))) %>% 
  filter(score == max(score))

# A tibble: 1 x 3
#     setID string score
#     <int> <chr>  <dbl>
#   1     4 abca       3
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("a", "b", "c", "c")), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
df2 <- 
  structure(list(setID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
                 col1 = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "w", "v", "c", "b", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a")), 
            class = "data.frame", 
            row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"))
```

Comment: Hi. Can you tell me if this is matching all the elements of df1 at the same time to df2? The reason why I wanted a sliding window approach is that I want to find a match without having to use all of df1. Granted this sample data isnt long enough to make that obvious. But in the actual data I have more than 1000 rows in df1 and more than 10 million in df2. So I am looking for a solution that matches df1 to a setID of df2 before going through all rows of df1. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Yes this is matching all of df1 (actually all subsets) to df2, this could take long but mabye you can just try it on a subset of your data and see how long it takes